# Requirejs + jQuery fails, but only when served remotely

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

My app has been working locally with Requirejs for some time without problems now, but when I put it on a remote server I start seeing Requirejs related problems again.

I have a jQuery wrapper script in which I load the actual jquery and some jQuery plugins, e.g. jquery.cookie.

```
## boot.js

// Loaded via <script data-main="/boot.js" src="/vendor/requirejs/require.js"></script>
require({
  baseUrl: '/vendor/requirejs/',
  waitSeconds: 5,
  paths: {
    jquery: '/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery',
    jQuery: '/assets/javascripts/jquery-wrapper',
  }
}, [
  'jQuery'
], function($) {
    ...
  });
});

## /assets/javascripts/jquery-wrapper.js

define([
  'order!jquery',
  'order!/vendor/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js'
], function($) {
  // In here I also define some on my own functions on $

  return $;
});
```

The problem is when I access the app on the remote server, `jQuery' is undefined at the point the jquery.cookie script is evaluated, implying to me that it is running before jQuery has been loaded.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.cookie.js:47
    (anonymous function) jquery.cookie.js:47
```

I though the order! prefix should prevent such a thing happening?

Again this works fine locally. It is only when serving off a remote server that I encouter the problem.

If it's relevant, locally I am using a Thin server. Remotely I also use Thin but behind Nginx, although Nginx is just proxying absolutely everything to Thin.

There is no indication that files are not being found within the 5 second timeout. The error appears in the console immediately.

Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong?

Thanks

Comment: 'order!/vendor/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js' is incorrect. Take out the ".js". Also most everyone puts the basePath and paths array in a call to the 'configure' method. There could be much more wrong here, but I think those two stand out as problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong in the way you are loading JQuery using the order plugin, but if it works locally and not remotely, you can check the HTTP header of the files returned by the server, and see if they support browser caching (Cache-Control, Pragma, Expires, ...), because the order plugin only works if the javascript files are cacheable by the browser.

If this is not the case, maybe you can load JQuery using priority on your RequireJS configuration, to load JQuery before the other plugins, or if you want, you can also wrap the plungis in define functions

```
define(['JQuery'], function ($) {
    //Paste plugin code here.
});
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I wasn't aware of the significane of caching there. That could explain some things (we came across these problems with a local server today too, but that was Webrick). I'll check and get back as soon as I can. Thanks Gabriel.

Comment: You little beauty @GabrielJürgens !